# Not Enough Space to Show Ads Android Issue

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to show Admob ads in my application and i keep getting the following error "Not Enough space to show ad. Need 480 X 75 pixels but only has 400 X 0 pixels". I am using the below xml.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lySearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:hint="Search Cards..."
        android:inputType="text" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@drawable/action_search"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
         />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCat"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lySearch"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="List Of Categories"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtCat" />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnAddViewDeck"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listView"
    android:text="Add/View Decks" />

             <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxx"
                     ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                     android:layout_below="@+id/btnAddViewDeck" 
                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

                     />
```

I tried experimenting with various different width and height but still the issue persists. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that you have told listView to consume all the height. You haven;'t shown the layout for the container, but if you switch to LinearLayout then you can change it to consume all remaining space instead:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

Something has also consumed some of the left and right padding. It's either you unshown RelativeLayout container or is coming from s style. In any case remove the padding or margin.